# Logstash not working with multiple files wildcard path

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

Logstash doesn't seem to read path with wildcard
here is my config file

```
input {
    file {
        path => "C:\logs\app*.log"
        type => "MyType"            
    }   
}
filter {
}
output {
    elasticsearch {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by replacing the backslash with slash.

```
C:/logs/app*.log
```

Comment: Have you tried to escape the backslash, i.e. `"C:\\logs\\app*.log"`?

Answer (score 5):

Just in case someone needs it, when using wildcard (*) with logstash in windows operating system, use forward slash (/) instead of back slash (\).

Following is the detail of the issue
https://github.com/cityindex-attic/logsearch/issues/100