# Config logstash: multiple input

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I need help to configure logstash: my configuration works perfectly with simple path (without stars) and when i put a stars (*) to select more than 1 file, it doesn't works.

Work:

```
file {
path => 'C:\MAMP\logs\access.log'
type => "apache_access"
}
```

Don't work:

```
file {
path => 'C:\MAMP\logs\*.log'
type => "apache_access"
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if this question was already ask, I put this answer here because this is not a common error.

"Just in case someone needs it, when using wildcard (*) with logstash in windows operating system, use forward slash (/) instead of back slash ().

I was able to resolve this issue by replacing the backslash with slash.

C:/logs/app*.log"

[Logstash not working with multiple files wildcard path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34658335/logstash-not-working-with-multiple-files-wildcard-path)